# Removing hspace and vspace from matplotlib canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

```
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100,facecolor='w'):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi,facecolor=facecolor)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
```

I just want to remove the red area.

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You want: `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)`. `hspace` and `wspace` only affect space between subplot axes.